# Unable to read and print full text hidden behind ellipsis on Console using Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to automate 'https://www.noon.com/uae-en/' and there I wanted to get full text of the first product named "U-HOOME Push Pop
Bubble Fidget Sensor…" in the carousel in Recommended for you. But the full name of the product is "U-HOOME Push Pop
Bubble Fidget Sensory Toy 13x13x2cm" which can be seen if we hover on the '...' stuff. Seems like ellipsis is added.

I tried using the following code.

```
List<WebElement> dem=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[data-qa='product-name']>span>span>span>span"));
        try {
            System.out.println(dem.get(0).getCssValue("text-overflow"));
            System.out.println("Printed the value of dem element.");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed.");
        }
```

The output what this gave me is,

clip
Printed the value of dem element.

So that shows that getcssValue("text-overflow") did not work for me. Also have a doubt whether the locator I used is correct or not.

Not necessary to hover on '...'. Even if we hover on complete product name in the middle, we can see the full name of the product which is truncated using some css functionality. Attached is the image of hover text.

[image: Hover image]

Please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessary to **hover**, there's a div that has a title :

**div :**

```
<div class="kcs0h5-0 diNcmV grid" title="U-HOOME Push Pop Bubble Fidget Sensory Toy 13x13x2cm ">
```

**code :**

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.noon.com/uae-en/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0, 500)");
String toolTip = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@data-qa='widget_productCarousel']/descendant::a/div"))).getAttribute("title");
System.out.println(toolTip);
```

**Output :**

> U-HOOME Push Pop Bubble Fidget Sensory Toy 13x13x2cm